# Harry Potter fanfic. Molly Weasley cares for Snape. He develops a crush

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Hurt comfort style fanfic. Primarily from Snape's POV. Molly feels bad for him or something with the spying and has started applying some TLC to him. Food is involved I think. He develops a crush on her. May have hired a prostitute to look like her just for comfort. Molly might have some kind of heritage that encourages crushes on her? Arthur is aware and understanding.